# Difference creating Singleton by class method and instance method

Tags: objective-c

What are the implications of creating a singleton class with:

```
+ (id)sharedCoordinator {
    static MyCoordinator *sharedCoordinator = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedCoordinator = [[self alloc] init];
    });
}
```

or as an instance method in the Application Delegate with class method:

```
- (CoreDataHelper *)cdh {
    if (!_coreDataHelper) {
        static dispatch_once_t predicate;
        dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
            _coreDataHelper = [CoreDataHelper new];
        });
        [_coreDataHelper setupCoreData];
    }
    return _coreDataHelper;
}
```

I have seen them both used, and would like to learn how they affect performance, simple code, debugging, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that the second code snippet has an error: when `cdh` is accessed concurrently from multiple threads, there is a possibility of `[_coreDataHelper setupCoreData]` being called twice.

This would happen if multiple threads arrived at `cdh` at the time when `_coreDataHelper` is `nil`. Only one of these threads would proceed to make the `[CoreDataHelper new]` call, yet all threads would end up in the `setupCoreData` method.

The proper way of doing initialization is to place the setup call into the block, and make the call unconditional:

```
- (CoreDataHelper *)cdh {
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        _coreDataHelper = [CoreDataHelper new];
        [_coreDataHelper setupCoreData];
    });
    return _coreDataHelper;
}
```

Now the two snippets look almost identical. The only difference is that the first snippet uses a method-static variable to store the singleton, while the updated second snippet "piggybacks" on the instance of app delegate.

This does not create any performance differences worth discussing. The biggest difference is that the ***first snippet lets you access the singleton without creating an additional dependency on the app delegate***, which is a good thing: this avoids "polluting" your app delegate with code that is not directly relevant to the application state.

Answer (score 0):

The first allows the `Singleton` class to be re-used in other places.
The second makes the single instance private to the app delegate.

Generally the first option is better (IMHO.) It allows you to reuse the single instance in a structured way anywhere in your code.

The second option can provide a guarantee of being a single instance, privately accessible in one place. That is probably useful in some circumstances, but it isn't really a `Singleton`. You could make this a public property on the AppDelegate, but then why not use a `Singleton` class?

As for performance considerations, they should be negliable. The only one I can think of is the slight extra overhead in the runtime caused by having an extra `class` object in your code.